# Standard Library vs Windows API Speed

Tags: c, windows

My question is about whether or not I should use the Windows API if I'm trying to get the most speed out of my program, where I could instead use a Standard Library function.

I assume the answer isn't consistent among every call; Specifically, I'm curious about stat() vs dwFileAttributes, if I wanted to figure out if a file was a directory or not for example (assuming file_name is a string containing the full path to the file):

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA fileData;
HANDLE          hSearch;

hSearch = FindFirstFile(TEXT(file_name), &fileData);

int isDir = fileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY
```

vs.

```
struct stat info;
stat(file_name, &info);

int isDir = S_ISDIR(info.st_mode);
```

If anyone knows, or can elaborate on what the speed difference between these libraries generally is (if any) I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an answer regarding speed, but @The Corn Inspector, the MSVC CRT code is open sourced.  If you look at an older version ( before .net and common UCRT), and look at the stat() function, it is INDEED a wrapper around the same OS call.

```
int __cdecl _tstat (
        REG1 const _TSCHAR *name,
        REG2 struct _stat *buf
        )
{  // stuff omitted for clarity
        _TSCHAR *  path;
        _TSCHAR    pathbuf[ _MAX_PATH ];
        int drive;          /* A: = 1, B: = 2, etc. */
        HANDLE findhandle;
        WIN32_FIND_DATA findbuf;

        /* Call Find Match File */
        findhandle = FindFirstFile((_TSCHAR *)name, &findbuf);
```

Of course there is addtional code for mapping structures, etc. Looks like it also does some time conversion:

```
 SYSTEMTIME SystemTime;
            FILETIME LocalFTime;

            if ( !FileTimeToLocalFileTime( &findbuf.ftLastWriteTime,
                                           &LocalFTime )            ||
                 !FileTimeToSystemTime( &LocalFTime, &SystemTime ) )
            {
```

so theoretically, it could be slower, but probably so insignificant, as to make no practical difference in the context of a complete, complex program.  If you are calling stat() a million times, and worry about milliseconds, who knows.  Profile it.